# Changing the sequence of test cases in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

For example,

[image: Here is the image. Feel sorry for my lack of reputation.]

I have several test cases here when recording. And now I want to take test case "exp11141" to the first one, but I can't drag and drop the test case in Selenium IDE.

Is there a way to change the sequence of test cases in Selenium IDE?

I mean just in the IDE, not to modify any code. Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't think that is possible just in the selenium IDE. You can export test suite, change the order, then save it, and open test suite from IDE. Not sure if this will work but it's worth trying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to drag and drop, that is part of the IDE functionality. If that isn't working then something may be wrong with your IDE install. Other than that there is no other way within the IDE to reorder the tests, you'd need to build the suite again by adding in the test cases from the file menu.

I'm not sure why you're against editing it outside of the IDE, but it is incredibly simple, as it would just be 1 cut and paste. If you open the suite file in a text editor you'll see something like this within it.

```
<body>
<table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium"><tbody>
<tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="TestCase1.html">TestCase1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="TestCase2.html">TestCase2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="TestCase3.html">TestCase3</a></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
```

All you'd need to do is cut the row of the test case you want to move and paste it in at the top

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can! (control the order of the tests in the User Interface)

I don't recall when this was introduced but I'm currently running v3.17.0.

In Selenium IDE by default you're looking at Tests which shows the tests, I believe, in the chronological order you recorded them.

If you click the word "Tests", and choose instead "Test Suites" you should see the default test suite. In that view you can add a new suite or use the Default Suite.

Taking the Default Suite as our example, to the right of the name of the suite you'll see an icon (for me in Windows it's triple dots stacked vertically)

Clicking that icon gives a menu that allows you to choose:

- Add tests
- Rename
- Delete
- Settings
- Export

By clicking "Add tests" you get a select tests dialogue with the names of all your saved tests, each with a checkbox beside it. Check any unchecked checkboxes first. **All of them!**

Now press enter to save or, if they were all already checked, escape to exit.

Now, viewing your suite you **CAN** click and drag to re-order the tests! So for the OP's question, in the suite click and drag that one to the top and off you go!

When you run a suite (icon with right-pointing triangle and three horizontal lines) or using shortcut (Ctrl-Shift-R) the tests will run in that order.

By creating different suites, I have created alternate combinations of tests from my total list to run different scenarios.